# gcov can't find a file. Mac OSX

Tags: macos, gcov

I have a problem with invoking gcov, it keeps returning - No such file or directory.

When I call

> ```
> localhost:R-3.0.1 romantsegelskyi$ gcov src/main/eval.c  
> eval.c: No such file or directory
> ```

However file itself and information needed for gcov exists.

> ```
> localhost:R-3.0.1 romantsegelskyi$ ls src/main/eval*
> src/main/eval.c       src/main/eval.d     src/main/eval.gcda  src/main/eval.gcno  src/main/eval.o
> ```

I have tried specifying --object-directory but still no luck

> ```
> localhost:R-3.0.1 romantsegelskyi$ gcov src/main/eval.c --object-directory=./src/main
> eval.c: No such file or directory
> ```

Strangest thing is that it is only the case on OSX, on Linux everything works fine as intended. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the filename (or command) doesn't have any weird/invisible characters? Try `ls src/main/eval.c` (from the same context as the `gcov` command).

Comment: Seems to work okay, 

localhost:R-3.0.1 romantsegelskyi$ ls src/main/eval.c

src/main/eval.c

Answer (score -3):

- Same behavior !! And more strange : I get the result (the .gcov file), following this mesg !! Perhaps, you have the result too ?
- There two aspects in the problem :

  - gcov manual said that gcov should execute by default in the directory where the object file and the gcov data files are. The first and simplest working solution is : go in the appropriate directory and execute gcov **cd src/main; gcov eval.c**
  - why the --object-directory=... arg seems not working ? Because the expected value is a directory name and in the example given, it is a file name. So you should write **--object-directory=src/main** (this work too)
    or **--object-file=src/main/eval.c** (according to the doc. I haven't tried this !)